# How to change the default text editor in ranger?

Tags: vim, ranger

Currently, ranger will only open text files with nano, and I want it to open them with vim.

As per the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ranger#Installation) I have tried adding

```
has xdg-open, flag f = xdg-open "$1"
ext txt = vim "$@"
```

to rifle.conf, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 28):

**You don't have to edit `.bashrc`, only the ranger config. Here is how:**

After startup, ranger creates a directory `~/.config/ranger`.

You want to edit the `rifle.conf` file. Rifle is the program that chooses what to open files with. To copy the default configuration for rifle to this directory, issue the following command:

```
$ ranger --copy-config=rifle.conf
```

(Alternatively, add all of rangers config files with `$ ranger --copy-config=all`)

In `rifle.conf`, find this part. Change the `$EDITOR` variable on the two lines  below:

```
#-------------------------------------------
# Misc
#-------------------------------------------
# Define the "editor" for text files as first action
mime ^text,  label editor = $EDITOR -- "$@"
mime ^text,  label pager  = "$PAGER" -- "$@"
!mime ^text, label editor, ext xml|json|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|js|sh|php = $EDITOR -- "$@"
!mime ^text, label pager,  ext xml|json|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|js|sh|php = "$PAGER" -- "$@"
```

Change it to whatever you want to edit text files with, like `vim`. I use Kakoune, so I change it to `kak`:

```
#-------------------------------------------
# Misc
#-------------------------------------------
# Define the "editor" for text files as first action
mime ^text,  label editor = kak -- "$@"
mime ^text,  label pager  = "$PAGER" -- "$@"
!mime ^text, label editor, ext xml|json|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|js|sh|php = kak -- "$@"
!mime ^text, label pager,  ext xml|json|csv|tex|py|pl|rb|js|sh|php = "$PAGER" -- "$@"
```

This was done on ranger version 1.8.1.

Comment: In later versions (currently I'm using 1.9.3) command to copy the config is `ranger --copy-config=rifle`.

Answer (score 23):

I figured it out.

If you are using BASH, add the following to your .bashrc :

```
 export VISUAL=vim;
 export EDITOR=vim;
```

otherwise, follow [these instructions](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acnc)

Comment: Also you can set an alias to set these env. variables and start ranger if you only want to use vim when you open a file with ranger.

Answer (score 11):

- Open `ranger`, press <kbd>S</kbd>, that will open `ranger`'s shell
- Then enter `select-editor`, it will show a numbered list of aveilable options and you have to enter the numer of the option that you want.

Comment: Usually people want to know things while using Ranger. This is the most useful answer. Succinct and precise.

Answer (score 2):

It is also worth considering the difference between pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and pressing <kbd>E</kbd> on the file that you want to edit

```
export VISUAL=vim;
export EDITOR=vim;
```

Though this solution might work when you press <kbd>E</kbd> on the file but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> may vary.