# Ranger: set default apps for files

Tags: vim, rc, xdg-open, ranger, nvim

I use arch linux, ranger and nvim. When I try to open any text file, ranger does not do anything and this is on output:

```
/bin/sh: line 1: vim: command not found
```

What can i do to open file in neovim ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this might help
[How to change the default text editor in ranger?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367452/how-to-change-the-default-text-editor-in-ranger)

what happens when you call 'vim' directly from the shell?

Comment: I do have vim installed at all. I use neovim 100% time